# Is it possible to get push notification stats like count of deliveries and opens when sending messages through Firebase notification API?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

We are about to switch to Firebase notifiaction API from Parse.com (that are retiring their service in jan 2017) to send push notification to our android and iOS Apps.

My question now is that I can't see any statistics about counts of successful deliveries and opens in the Firebase Console for a specific message ? The only thing we get when posting to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send is a `message_id`

```
{"message_id":123456789}
```

But I havn't seen any documentation on a api how to follow up a sent message with this `message_id`. And the Firebase console has only the these kind of stats for messages created in the Console Gui, not the one create through an api post.

These stats was availible in Parse.com. But it seems as Firebase Cloud Messaging is a bit more low level, and perhaps these stats doesn't come out the box, so they might have to be custom made in a logging app etc by sending back events from the apps when messages as received and opened etc. Or is there a standardized way that I've missed when reading the Firebase Notification api docs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send notifications from the Firebase Notifications console, you get statistics about how many people received and opened the messages. But there is no API (yet) for Firebase Notifications.

If you're using the Firebase Cloud Messaging API (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send), the message statistics don't show up in the Firebase Notifications console. You can (as AL. says) get delivery statistics in the Google Play Developer Console in that case.

Comment: Is it possible to also see the iOS statistics when sending notifications with FCM API? I can see the delivery and registration statistics in Google Play but that's only for Android if I'm correct.

Comment: iOS stats are available for sends but not for impressions and opens when using the FCM API.

Comment: @frank We are using Firebase cloud messaging API and we are able to see Stats for iOS(Sends & Open Count) but not for Android. Any Solution ?

Answer (score 2):

firebase allows you to view sent/delivered/opened statuses by default from their website
http://console.firebase.google.com
at the notification section

but I am not sure about the parse.com implementations

also if you are a new comer to firebase let it collect user data for about 24 hours after successfully migrating to firebase
I found that in the first day the notifications weren't really reporting immediately

Comment: Thanks @iceman2894 yes I can see the status for messages created in the console gui, but unfortunately the messages sent the fcm push api are not included in that status list.

Comment: yes the GUI only records messeges sent using the console .. and for the http request it only sends back the id if success or the error message, a workaround here is to implement a part in your app notification reciever to notify your server about delivery and open events.

Comment: as of http limitations it cannot wait for the user to act then responds back.

Answer (score 1):

<s>I think you're looking for the [FCM Diagnostics and Statistics](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en) feature.</s>

However, this is not visible in the Firebase Console, only in your Google Play Developer Console. And the feature only works if your app is at least in Alpha Testing.

Comment: Thanks AL. I will give that a try and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the report of messaging , check the following link:

https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/<*** Project Name here ***>/messaging/reports