# How to reflect push notifications sent by API on Firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications, firebase-console

We are using Firebase API (CURL to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send) to send push notifications to multiple devices by topic but when we send them these are not reflected on the console. We can only see notifications sent by the console.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

The charts in the Firebase Notifications console only reflect messages sent from that console. It does not count messages sent by the Firebase Cloud Messaging API.

Also see my answer here: [Is it possible to get push notification stats like count of deliveries and opens when sending messages through Firebase notification API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40065002/is-it-possible-to-get-push-notification-stats-like-count-of-deliveries-and-opens/40067338#40067338)