# Check result of sent message via REST API on Google FCM?

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I send message to Google FCM server via REST API the response body has `message_id` data. Can I use that id to get information about the message (delivery time etc.) ? Here is the communication:

**Request**:

URL:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send   POST
```

Headers:

```
Content-Type    application/json
Authorization   key=MY_KEY
```

Body

```
{
   "to": "/topics/fls",
   "data": {
      "count": "21",
   }
}
```

**Response**

Body

```
{"message_id":1234}
```

So I need to check result info via REST like this:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/info?message_id=1234
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no such API that you could use to retrieve the details of a sent message.

What is currently available is the [Diagnostics Tool](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en), keeping in mind that [this is not visible in the Firebase Console, only in your Google Play Developer Console and the feature only works if your app is at least in Alpha Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40065191/4625829).

Comment: Well in this case the only solution is the user who received the message should communicate the app server again to say "I received this" right?

Comment: If you just want to confirm the delivery, then yeah. [Delivery Receipt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40110224/4625829) should work.

Comment: This seems like it should be a Firebase Console feature considering you can send push notifications to iOS without even having an android app.